# canvas to ffmpeg - invalid data error

Tags: javascript, canvas, ffmpeg, pipe, rgb

I'm curently trying to pipe some raw data directly into ffmpeg. The data comes from a canvas. What I do is the following:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,600,600);
var dataArray = imageData.data;
var rgbArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i+=4) {
    rgbArray.push([dataArray[i], dataArray[i+1], dataArray[i+2]])
}

var rgb24Array = rgbArray.map(function(rgbList){
    return (rgbList[0] << 16) | (rgbList[1] << 8) | (rgbList[2])
});
```

The ffmpegArgs are set like this:

```
var ffmpegArgs = [
    '-c:v', 'rawvideo' // input container
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', // input pixel format
    '-s', '600x600' //input size
    '-i', 'pipe:0', // input source
    '-format', 'mp4', // output container format
    '-c:v', 'libx264', // output video codec
    '-b:v', '2m', // output bitrate
    'udp://239.255.123.46:1234' // output destination
];
```

So basically, the imageData I get from the canvas has 4 elements for each pixel (rgba), I first filter out the rgb values and then pack them to send them to ffmpeg, I directly pipe them in like `ffmpeg.stdin.write(rgb24Array)`.

But I get a `TypeError: invalid data` and I'm not sure why... I also tried to leave data as it is and use `rgba` as `pix_fmt`, but same error.

The stacktrace of the error is:

```
TypeError: invalid data
   at Socket.write (net.js:617:11)
   at null._repeat (....line with ffmpeg.stdin.write() in it)
   at wrapper [as_onTimeout] (timers.js:275:11)
   at Timer.listonTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Does anybody have a idea where the problem could be?

**Edit:**
changed some things, first, I now use a Uint8Array:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,600,600);
            var srcArray = imageData.data;
            var dstArray = new Uint8Array(imageData.width * imageData.height * 3);
            for(var i = 0, p = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) { // i++ skips alpha
              dstArray[p++] = srcArray[i++];                   // red comp. and incr.
              dstArray[p++] = srcArray[i++];                   // green comp. and incr.
              dstArray[p++] = srcArray[i++];                   // blue comp. and incr.
            }

            ffmpeg.stdin.write(dstArray);
```

Also added `-video_size` parameter to the ffmpegArgs. But still it's not working and I get the same errors.

Comment: I'm on my way out (deleted answer for now). I'll revisit sometime later today if I can. In the meantime there might be someone else who are familiar with the problem related to the socket/protocol etc.

Comment: @K3N okay, thank you anyway..

Comment: Did you ever solve this?